# JavaScript smooth scroll not working in safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created small menu order application, I have added 5 menu categories is Desserts, salad, thai noodles and more using horizontal scroll bar. if I click salad or any categories move left and right position working fine in chrome. I checking  safari browser not working horizontal scroll. what I am missing. could you please check and let me know.

html:

```
<div class="menu" id="menu">
                  <div class="topnav sticky" id="stickyMenu"><span data-id="appetizers" id="nav1" class="cat-nav">Appetizers</span><span data-id="desserts" id="nav2" class="cat-nav">Desserts</span><span data-id="pizza--classic-11-inches-" id="nav3" class="cat-nav active">Pizza (Classic 11 inches)</span><span data-id="salad" id="nav4" class="cat-nav">Salad</span><span data-id="thai-noodles" id="nav5" class="cat-nav">Thai Noodles</span></div>
                  <!-- <div class="row filter">
                     <input type="text" id="gsearch" class="form-control gsearch"  placeholder="Search within this Menu...">
                     </div> -->
               </div>
```

js code:

```
 $(document).on('click', ".topnav .cat-nav", function(e) {
            $(".topnav .cat-nav").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");

            var target = $(this).data("id");
            $('html, body').animate({
               scrollTop: ($("#"+target).offset().top - 50)
            }, 500);
        });
         $(window).scroll(function() {
            //get current sroll position
            var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop(); 
            //get the position of the containers
             var s=["appetizers","desserts","pizza--classic-11-inches-","salad","thai-noodles"];
            for (i=0; i<s.length; i++) {

               if (scrollPosition >= ($("#"+s[i]).offset().top) - 190) {

                  $("#nav"+(i+1)).addClass("active");  
                  $("#nav"+(i+1)).siblings().removeClass("active");  
                   // $('.cat-nav').scrollLeft(myScrollPos);
                  var element = document.querySelector(".active");
                  element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth" ,inline: "center"});
                  // $("#nav"+(i+1)).css({behavior: "smooth" ,inline: "center"});  
               }
            }
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: auto` to your `sticky` or `topnav` class:

```
.sticky {
   overflow: none;
   overflow-x: auto;
   display: block;
}
```

This might work.

Comment: Hi Raymond, not working above code shall i share demo url

Comment: I've changed my code, Try it again !

Comment: really awesome working fine thanks

Comment: your welcome, if you accept my answer and vote it up I would appreciated :)